# How to store in a variable the result of a function in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables, store

How I could store the result of this function in a string:

```
for($i=0; $i<=($totRows-1); $i++)
    {
        if($i<($totRows-1))
        { echo $objects[$i]['id'].","; }
        else
        { echo $objects[$i]['id']; }
    }
```

And for example it returns:

```
6,8,9
```

and I want to save it as a variable such as $var then when typing the following code:

```
echo $var;
```

I would have the same string

```
6,8,9
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$text = "";
for($i=0; $i<=($totRows-1); $i++)
    {
        if($i<($totRows-1))
        { $text .= $objects[$i]['id'].","; }
        else
        { $text .= $objects[$i]['id']; }
    }

echo $text;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I used this!

Comment: Hi, done I guess you mean by turning the sign check green. Isn't.

Comment: What do you earn from it. Because people seems to get conerned about this. What do you earn from giving more accurate answers than others?

Answer (score 4):

```
function foo($totRows, $objects)
{
    $return = "";
    for($i=0; $i<=($totRows-1); $i++)
    {
        if($i<($totRows-1))
        { $return .= $objects[$i]['id'].","; }
        else
        { $return.= $objects[$i]['id']; }
    }
    return $return;
}

$var = foo($totRows, $objects);
echo $var;
```

Comment: why do you use function? This won't work as $object's isn't in function's scope

Comment: The question was "How to store in a variable the result of a function in PHP"  Which implies that a function is expected.

Comment: asked mix function and for loop

Comment: @genesis: How is `$objects` not in the function's scope? It is a parameter of the function...

Comment: @animusion, I edited my answer, he was quite correct initially.  I should have added a comment, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getIDs( array $objects ) {
    foreach( $objects as $obj ) {
        $obj_array[] = $obj['id']
    }
    return $obj_array;
}
echo implode( ',', getIDs( $objects ) );
```

or in PHP 5.3+

```
function getIDs( array $objects ) {
    return array_map( function($v){return $v['id'];}, $objects );
}
echo implode( ',', getIDs( $objects ) );
```